# ES6 parameter destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In my code, this works:

```
storedResponse.headers.forEach(function(header){
            response.setHeader(header.name, header.value)
        });
```

whereas this fails:

```
storedResponse.headers.forEach(function({name,value}){
            response.setHeader(name, value)
        });
```

This is the same as section 2.5 here: http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html. Any pointers on what Im doing wrong here?

Im running this under node `4.2.4` (from node --version). The error message is:

```
/usr/local/bin/node --debug-brk=50852 server.js
Debugger listening on port 50852
/Users/shasn/WebstormProjects/Yama/server.js:22
        storedResponse.headers.forEach(({word, count}) => {
                                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:467:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: _"this fails"_ How? Is there an error? What happens? What environment are you running this code in?

Comment: @JLRishe Added more details, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Not supported in node v4 : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring  . Try with babel or traceur :-)